# The meaning of 得趣...to get a taste for something?

Tags: classical-chinese, traditional-characters, literature

More from Chouchengzhi.

I would appreciate thoughts on my translation of the following...my supervisor doesn't like my translation of 得趣 at all! Does it mean something more like 'to get a taste for something'?

伏念襄。穀城之種。曹溪之流。王，謝相隨。擅風流於江左。嵇，劉得趣。寄閑情於竹林。

Brew (Yang) is of the genus of Grain Citadel (Gucheng), and the current of Dregs Creek (Caoxi). The Wang and Xie families both followed [the Yang family], and monopolised elegance and civilisation south of the lower reaches of the Yangtze. Xi [Kang] and Liu [Ling] shared a past-time [with the Yang family],  living in seclusion in the bamboo grove.

Comment: Does it mean maybe to get attention/be noticed by someone?

Comment: Googled 愁城志, it's an ancient Korean novel written in Chinese, interesting. 得趣 translated literally means "gain happiness/fun", so here might mean 嵇, 刘 live a happy life in the bamboo forest.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise 趣 could just be happiness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

得趣 = technical term in Taoism. to find true meaning. Often used for the meaning (or pleasures), that hermits find in their surroundings.

朝退常歸隱，真修大隱情。園林應得趣，巖谷自爲名

Where are you getting the Yang family?

Comment: In this passage General Malt (Guk Yang) is writing his own biography...Should be Guk family*